# How to push a view to the navigation stack and remove the current one?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I would like to push a view into the navigation controller stack but remove the current one so when the users press back on the next view it does't take them to the previous view.

The flow in one direction could be one of these:

```
View X -> View 1 -> View 2 -> View 3    
View X -> View 1      ->      View 3
```

But the flow in the oposite direction is always like this:

```
View X <- View 1      <-      View 3
```

The problem is that I want to handle it on the View 2 Controller, doing it on the View 3 is easy overriding the back button action. The View 3 can be a lot of different views and I don't want to override the back button for all of them and check if the previous controller of the stack is the View 2 Controller. They all have the same parent class, so I can't override the back button for just the 'View 3 class' controllers.

I've tried this so the controller of the View 2 is not added into the navigation stack:

```
//Pop controller from stack before pushing
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

But once you pop it removes the view and doesn't push to the next controller

Other option with the same result

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[viewControllers removeObjectIdenticalTo:self];
self.navigationController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: You need to use unwind segues.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that it has to be compatible with 5.1

Comment: Ah, then the only way is to pop twice. You can't do what you are looking for directly but you can call popViewController twice or you can do popToViewController and pass in View 1 to go straight back to View 1.

Comment: Yes, from View Controller 3 I can pop twice, but I need to do it on the View Controller 2, removing the view from the stack before or after pushing to the next view

Comment: No you don't. You can pop twice from VC3. Not sure why you think you need to remove VC2 though?

Comment: It's just the way my controllers are designed, **View 1** can be a lot of different controllers, as well as **View 3**, and **View 3** doesn't know who the **View 1** controller is without looking the stack. **View 2** can appear sometimes and other times the flow is going directly from **View 1 -> View 3**. I just want to include the logic into the **View Controller 2** so I don't have to check who the previous controller is in all **View 3** Controllers. That's why I was thinking of removing **View 2** from the stack.

Comment: try popToRootViewControllerAnimated:

Comment: thanks, but View 1 is not the root controller of the navigation and I'm trying to implement the logic on the View 2 Controller, the popToRootViewController should be executed on the View 3.

Comment: Does your design allow you to put any code into view1 to help with this?

Comment: Yes, adding code to view 1 can be an option!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In regards to your last example that isn't pushing, does this work?

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[viewControllers removeObjectIdenticalTo:self];
[viewControllers addObject:controller];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers: viewControllers animated: YES];
```

Since you set the controllers to an array of controllers without yourself, you might be setting your `navigationController` property to `nil`, making you unable to push the new one immediately after. It doesn't hurt to try, anyways.

Comment: yeah!!, that worked! It's doing a weird effect with the title of the navigation bar (it's a little bit customized) but at least is moving to the next view and returning to the correct one, so it seems as the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar use-case and this was the solution that I came up in Swift 5:

```
      if var controllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers {
        // finding 'View 2' to remove from navigation stack
        if let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: 'View 2') {
          controllers.remove(at: index)
        }
        controllers.append('View 3') // adding new viewController to navigation stack
        // this will update the navigation stack with system animation
        self.rootNavController.setViewControllers(controllers, animated: true)
      } else {
        // fallback scenario
        self. self.navigationController.pushViewController('View 3', animated: true)
      }
```